# How to remove background from p:breadCrumb

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have this `breadCrumb`. How I can remove the background. I want just to display the links without any background.

```
<h:form>
    <p:breadCrumb style="font-size:11px;">
        <p:menuitem value="Datacenters" url="#" />
        <p:menuitem value="Zone" url="#" />
        <p:menuitem value="Rack" url="#" />
        <p:menuitem value="Server" url="#" />
        <p:menuitem value="Processor" url="#" />
        <p:menuitem value="RAM" url="#" />
        <p:menuitem value="HDD" url="#" />
    </p:breadCrumb>
</h:form>
```

Into the manual I found that I have to change the css class `.ui-breadcrumb` in order to change the background. But how I can override the background?

P.S

This is the css class responsible for background:

```
.ui-widget-header {
    background: url("/DX-57/RMC-57/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-bg_diagonals-   thick_6_333333_40x40.png.html?ln=primefaces-aristo") repeat scroll 50% 50% #333333;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .css file (at the end of it), or in your header in  tags:

```
.ui-breadcrumb{background-color: none;}
```

More i can´t do with this less informations.

edit:
If that doesn´t work:

```
.ui-breadcrumb{background-color: none!important;}
```

that should do the trick.

another edit: if it´s an image:

```
.ui-breadcrumb{background-image: none;}
```

Comment: which background? that doesn´t help...i can´t figure out what you want...i´m sorry

Comment: Hope i could help you in anyway.

Comment: This is not working for me. tried including `.ui-breadcrumb{background-image: none;}` and `.p-breadcrumb{background-image: none;}`
Can you please help me out

Answer (score 1):

.breadcrumb{ background-color : unset !important; }

Comment: Hi, please put the code in snippet for readability (`ctrl + k`) and explain your code.
Code only answer will be flagged as low effort.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Use bg-transparent style from bootstrap.

Comment: How is that going to help?